# Error: "per-mode" is undefined

Tags: siunitx

The simple expression:

```
$v_f = \SI[per-mode=fraction]{32}{\meter\per\second}$
```

when parsed, yields the following error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `per-mode' undefined in families `key'.
```

However, removing `[per-mode=fraction]` causes it to work fine. How can I print this as a fractional unit?

Comment: You're probably using an old version of `siunitx`. Try updating to the current version (2.5c).

Comment: @Jake How do I determine the version?

Comment: @Jake Okay, I've got version `1.3`. I installed `siunitx` by installing the `texlive-science` package, so what is the best way of updating?

Comment: @Arafinwe If you're using the TeX Live 2009 that's provided by Debian/Ubuntu you're out of luck. You can install the 2012 version with this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa), but this method doesn't guarantee that the *last* version of packages is in the distribution. You may want to install a ["vanilla TeX Live"](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

Comment: @Jake Thanks for your comment. If you should re-post that as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have suggested upgrade your `siunitx`, but that may not be so easy. The option for version one was called just `per`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per = fraction}
\begin{document}
$v_f = \SI{32}{\meter\per\second}$
\end{document}
```

If you give a version one option in the preamble, version two will pick this up an act appropriately.