# xkeyval gives error with siunitx on some LaTeX installations

Tags: siunitx, xkeyval

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI[per-mode = fraction]{3.00e8}{\meter\per\second}

\end{document}
```

I've tested this on three different computers, all running TexLive 2009 (the one that comes with Ubuntu or Linux Mint), and got an error message on one of them:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `per-mode' undefined in families `key'.
```

More generally, any attempt to provide an extra option to `siunitx` (e.g., `output-decimal-marker = {,}`, which I also need) leads to the same error.

I suspect this is a clash of versions between `xkeyval` and `siunitx`, but so far haven't been able to pinpoint what is different in that computer that produces the error. I even removed the LaTeX3 package to no avail.

A similar question was asked on [Error: "per-mode" is undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73693/error-per-mode-is-undefined), but the question is now closed.

Comment: Have you tried just using `\SI[per=fraction]...`?

Comment: You must use `\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use an option for version 2 of `siunix` but have version 1 installed. You should always check the manual for the version of `siunitx` (or any other package) you have installed to see what is valid. Here

```
texdoc siunitx
```

at the Terminal will show you that there is no `per-mode` option in version 1, but rather an option simply called `per`.

As you might expect, version 1 is more limited than version 2, and so you will have fewer abilities available. You *may* wish to do a 'local installation' of the latest release (v2.5q at the time of writing): that certainly will require an up-to-date LaTeX3 support package set. (Version 2 uses native LaTeX3 keyval processing, and does not load `xkyeval` at all.)